# SPSS side-by-side frequency table

Tags: spss

I have a file where each record is about a student. For example:

```
Student   ServiceA  ServiceB
Bob       ABC       ABC
Jane                ABC
Jim       XYZ       
Henry     EFG       ABC
Laura               EFG

Code for the above table:
data list list/student ServiceA  ServiceB (3a10).
begin data
"Bob","ABC","ABC"
"Jane","ABC",
"Jim",,"XYZ"       
"Henry","EFG","ABC"
"Laura","EFG",
end data.
```

I want to show a simple table that has the count of services for Service A and B, side by side, like this:

```
           ServiceA    ServiceB
[Blank]    2           1
ABC        1           3
EFG        1           1
XYZ        1           0
```

I've tried Custom Tables and Report Summaries in Rows / Columns, but can't seem to produce this simple table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This will put the analysis of both variables in the same table:

```
VARSTOCASES /make Service  from ServiceA  ServiceB/index src(service)/null=keep.
sort cases by src.
split file by src.
freq service.
split file off.
```

This still wont put the frequencies side by side, but you can now do that easily using the pivoting trays.